# Fabric -- connecting to hosts in ~/.ssh/config still prompts for passphrase

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm making use of `fabric.user_ssh_config = True`, and my ssh config looks like:

```
Host    server_vm1.domain.com
        IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa_uiuc
        IdentitiesOnly  yes
        User t2
```

However, I get prompted for a passphrase every time I connect to this machine (like it's looking at my standard `id_rsa` file, which *does* require a passphrase):

`[server_vm1.domain.com] Passphrase for private key:`

This happens when I try to do `fabric.api.put('ds.tar', '/root/test')`. The `User t2` is not the same as my local user (from where I'm running my fabric script). I can ssh from my terminal directly fine, with no prompts.

Comment: You can try `sshpass`

Comment: I don't think this helps me. The problem is it's using the wrong rsa key. My standard `id_rsa` file does require a password. The one fabric should be using from the config (id_rsa_uiuc) does not.

Comment: Try to exchange each other RSA key via backend or using shell script (from Server1 to Server2 and Server2 to Server1). So you can pass ssh without password.